# Password protect using zip and shadow file

Tags: centos

I'm looking to compress & password protect files via a script, without having to enter a password and instead use the password from /etc/shadow.

From the command line I would normally do something like:

```
zip -e <zip-file-name> <source-file-name>
```

But of course this prompts the user for the password.

My desire is to use the same password as the user account (root or any user) which is already located in /etc/shadow and not rely on another file somewhere to provide the password.

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion to this? (Doesn't have to necessarily use the 'zip' tool but should be a tool readily available in Centos8).

Comment: zip archive are also meant to be moved from computer to computer, thus password (hashed password) is encrypted within archive when crypt option is used. I do not know of utilities (save backup tools like Veeam) which relay on external hashed password database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do what you’re trying to do.

As mentioned in the comments, `/etc/shadow` doesn’t store passwords, it stores password hashes; these are non-reversible, so extracting a password from `/etc/shadow` is difficult (as in, extremely time-consuming) if not impossible.